# How to get correct time in Linux

Tags: c, linux, datetime, time

Currently I am able to receive the current date time with the help of functions like `localtime()` `gettimeofday()` etc from `time.h`

Suppose a user modifies the date and time settings in Linux to change the date to some previous date, I am getting those changes when I call the functions mentioned above.

I would still like to get the current time i.e say today's time irrespective of any user changing the system date & time settings.

Is there any way I could achieve the same ?

Comment: You can't, the system time is the system time and if it changes then it is changed. Also, how can you be sure _which_ time is the correct one, then one from before or after the update?

Comment: then instead of reading from your system read from some online server.

Comment: some Linux systems make their system time and date available as a standard service called daytime.`servinfo = getservbyname("daytime", "tcp");` from like google. If you need i can write a simple tcp client for you.

Answer (score 8):

As far as your computer is concerned, the system time *is* the current time.

If you can't trust the system you're on to provide accurate time, you might want to look into embedding an [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) [client](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%20ntp%20client) into your program.

Answer (score 2):

If a user with appropriate privileges changes the system time, then the system believes the new value.

So, the only way you can get someone else's opinion of the correct time is to go outside the system. For example, you could connect to a time server via the NTP protocol.

For a cheap and cheerful solution you could grab a web page such as http://www.whattimeisit.com/. Of course that will be inaccurate by (at best) the latency of the download, which is one of the things NTP clients cleverly deal with.

If what you want is not so much the "correct" time, as just a time that doesn't jump around while you're using it, then you could look into `clock_gettime` and specifically `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not synchronised to system time, you could look into reading the hardware clock, take a look at the [hwclock man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hwclock).

The notes section on that page has some info about how to check for synchronisation too.